# Why the loop stops right in the middle?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve Lucky Sevens problem where you need to return true if any 3 consecutive numbers in an array sum to 7. I know there is a better way to do it, but I want to use `.splice` here. For some reason the loop stops in the middle and don’t check the last six digits.

```
function seven(arr) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if((arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]) == 7) {
            document.body.innerHTML = “true”;
        }
        arr.splice(0,1);
        document.body.innerHTML = “false”;
}}
seven([1,5,7,1,5,2,1,5,3,1,5,1]);
```

Comment: You're both incrementing `i` and decrementing `arr.length` (via `splice`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting the arr element in the loop at  `arr.splice(0,1);`
and in the loop break condition `i<arr.length`; the length gets calculated at every iteration. So when you use splice the array changes and in arr.length will give you new length of array.

The solution with splice

```
function seven(arr) {
var len = arr.length
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if((arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]) == 7) {
            document.body.innerHTML = “true”;
        }
        arr.splice(0,1);
        document.body.innerHTML = “false”;
}}
seven([1,5,7,1,5,2,1,5,3,1,5,1]);
```

without splice

```
function seven(arr) {
    var len = arr.length -2
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if((arr[i] + arr[i+1] + arr[i+2]) == 7) {
                document.body.innerHTML = “true”;
            }
            document.body.innerHTML = “false”;
    }}
    seven([1,5,7,1,5,2,1,5,3,1,5,1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop.

```
function seven(arr) {
    while(arr.length > 2) {
        if((arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2]) == 7) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "true";
        }
        arr.splice(0,1);
        document.body.innerHTML = "false";
    }
}
seven([1,5,7,1,5,2,1,5,3,1,5,1]);
```

The loop will break if there are 2 elements but will run for the duration of existence of more than 2 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Its because value of "i" becomes equal to length of "arr" array after 5th iteration, condition

```
i < arr.length
```

in your loop stops the execution of for loop.